# How to apply multiple filters to the same image in Android using GPUimage?

Tags: android, image-processing, gpuimage

I was trying to apply two filters to the same image in Android, but the result is that only one filter of both is applied to the image. What am I doing wrong?

```
public void asignarFiltro(){

    gpuImage = new GPUImage(this);
    gpuImage.setImage(imagenOriginal);

    GPUImageFilterGroup group = new GPUImageFilterGroup();
    group.addFilter(new GPUImageGrayscaleFilter());
    group.addFilter(new GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter());

    List<GPUImageFilter> filters = group.getMergedFilters();
    Iterator<GPUImageFilter> iterator = filters.iterator();

    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        GPUImageFilter currentFilter = iterator.next();
        gpuImage.setFilter(currentFilter);
    }

    imageView.setImageBitmap(gpuImage.getBitmapWithFilterApplied());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes man you can. Just pass your GPUImageGroupFilter object to the gpuimage. Example gpuimage.setFilter(group);

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of using `GPUImageFilterGroup`:

```
List<GPUImageFilter> filterList = new ArrayList<>();

filterList.add(filter1);
filterList.add(filter2);
.
.
.
filterList.add(filterN);

GPUImageFilterGroup filterGroup = new GPUImageFilterGroup(filterList);

GPUImage gpuImage = new GPUImage(context);
gpuImage.setFilter(filterGroup);
```